# Need advices on iptables

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, rules

Helly guys ! :-) .

I need a (several?) advice(s) from you about my iptables setup.
I'm pretty new to iptables, and this is the first time I configure a server with iptables ONLY as a firewall (we don't have money nor time to set a "true" firewall upfront).

I'd like to connect to my server via SSH from only specific.location.com.

Therefore, I set up the following rules in INPUT :

```
target      in     out     source                       destination
ACCEPT      lo     any     localhost                    anywhere
ACCEPT      any    any     specific.location.com        myserver.local    tcp dpt:ssh
```

My default policies are :

```
INPUT DROP
FORWARD DROP
OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

With this first configuration, I was able to connect to my server, but unable to reach outside (like google.com), and the connection was very slow.

I understood that my firewall didn't have any rule including the state "ESTABLISHED" from a packet.
Indeed, I guess my packets were able to get out, but weren't allowed to come back...

So I added this rule :

```
target      in     out     source                       destination
ACCEPT      any    any     anywhere                     anywhere           state ESTABLISHED
```

Now all works like a charm, I can access outside from the server, the connection is very fast like before, and I can only access my server in SSH from specific.location.com !

My only question is that I need your advices, is that a clean configuration ? I don't find any example like this in internet, so I'm quite wondering...

Or did I just make a HUGE security fault ?!

Thanks for your help guys :-)

Comment: Using iptables on a dedicated machine like that _is_ a true firewall.

Comment: Yeah i feel it was quite hard to say that when I wrote this... I didn't mean that actually, I mean that usually, I used to work with  Cisco, fortigates and so, and never really used iptables in a production environment ;-)

Comment: iptables is a true firewall (like pf would be for BSD firewalls). Your rules are perfectly fine since packets accepted in the ESTABLSIHED state will either be replies to an open input port or replies to outgoing traffic initiated by the server himself.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, that's exactly this point I wasn't sure about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canonically, that ESTABLISHED rule is actually RELATED,ESTABLISHED.  It won't affect SSH or HTTP(S), though—the difference is that RELATED also encompasses what are *technically* new connections, but are related to an existing one, as in FTP data channel communications or ICMP echo replies.

Overall, what you have done here is just fine.

Comment: Many thanks for your advices BMDan !! I can now sleep without a worry :-)